# moving a turtle in a circle and stop it in the initial position as a ros node?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-18.04, ros

I ran the below code using rosrun command as a node but not running in a circle anymore. But there's no error in this function.
How to solve this and ran in a circle and stop in initial position?

ROS : Melodic
Ubuntu 18.04

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import rospkg
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from turtlesim.msg import Pose
#defining variables
x = 0
y = 0
theta = 0.0
    
#main function  
def pose_callback(msg):
    global x, y, psi
    x = msg.x
    y = msg.y
    psi = msg.theta
    print(msg.theta)
if __name__=="__main__":

    
    rospy.init_node('node_turtle_revolve', anonymous = True)
    r = rospy.Rate(10)
    velocity_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/turtle1/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10) 
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        
    sub = rospy.Subscriber('/turtle1/pose', Pose, pose_callback)
        vel_msg = Twist()
    vel_msg.linear.x = 0.2
    vel_msg.linear.x = 0.0
    vel_msg.linear.x = 0.0
    vel_msg.angular.x= 0.0
    vel_msg.angular.y= 0.0
    vel_msg.angular.z= 0.1
    velocity_publisher.publish(vel_msg)
    r.sleep
```

Comment: There is a space missing `if__name__=="__main__":` needs to be `if  __name__=="__main__":`

Comment: yeah, I rectified it but now turtle moving in same position not in circle

Comment: `vel_msg.linear.x = 0.0` ??

Comment: Stop position  vel_msg.linear.x = 0.0

Comment: you are setting your speed to zero. You have a typo and even though I point you to it you still don't see it. Is this homework?

Comment: sorry, I rectified it and fixed it to vel_msg.linear. y, z, and x = 0.2 . But can't stop turtle at starting point

Comment: yeah, of course not. You don't even have any check for whether you have arrived. Nor code to stop it. Also, you will need to learn about closed-loop control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change msg as pose

def pose_callback(pose):
global x, y, psi
x = pose.x
y = pose.y
psi = msg.theta
print(msg.theta)
And you should write a if statement

Comment: Thanks. I used that but still can't stop turtle at starting position